Synchronizing Metronome with Audio Input on Mobile Devices
I'm working on a Unity project for mobile devices where I need to synchronize a metronome with incoming audio from a microphone. The goal is to detect drum hits in real-time and align them with the metronome ticks. Below is a simplified version of my current DrumInput script:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DrumInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioClip microphoneClip; // Audio clip to capture microphone input
    private int sampleRate = 44100; // Sample rate for audio capture
    public float threshold = 0.1f; // Threshold to detect drum hits
    public int smoothingWindow = 10; // Window size for smoothing amplitude
    public float checkInterval = 0.01f; // Interval for checking audio input
    private float[] prevSamples; // Array to store previous samples for smoothing

    void Start()
    {
        StartMicrophone();
        prevSamples = new float[smoothingWindow];
        StartCoroutine(CheckAudio());
    }

    // Start capturing audio from the microphone
    void StartMicrophone()
    {
        string device = Microphone.devices[0];
        microphoneClip = Microphone.Start(device, true, 1, sampleRate);
    }

    // Coroutine to periodically check audio input
    IEnumerator CheckAudio()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null);
            float[] samples = new float[microphoneClip.samples * microphoneClip.channels];
            microphoneClip.GetData(samples, 0);
            ProcessAudio(samples, micPosition);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(checkInterval);
        }
    }

    // Process audio samples to detect drum hits
    void ProcessAudio(float[] samples, int micPosition)
    {
        float smoothedAmplitude = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < micPosition; i++)
        {
            smoothedAmplitude = (smoothedAmplitude * (smoothingWindow - 1) + Mathf.Abs(samples[i])) / smoothingWindow;
            prevSamples[i % smoothingWindow] = Mathf.Abs(samples[i]);

            if (smoothedAmplitude > threshold)
            {
                double currentTime = AudioSettings.dspTime;
                double inputLatency = (micPosition / (double)sampleRate);
                double adjustedHitTime = currentTime - inputLatency;
                
                Debug.Log($"Drum hit detected at: {currentTime:F1}, Adjusted Hit Time: {adjustedHitTime:F1}, Amplitude: {smoothedAmplitude}, Threshold exceeded by: {smoothedAmplitude - threshold}, Input Latency: {inputLatency * 1000:F1}ms (Compensation Time: {inputLatency:F4}s)");

                // Handle drum hit detection
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

The script captures audio input, processes it to detect drum hits, and attempts to compensate for input latency. However, I'm having difficulty achieving precise synchronization between the detected drum hits and the metronome ticks.Does anyone have experience or advice on how to better synchronize real-time audio input with a metronome in Unity, particularly for mobile devices? Any tips on improving the accuracy of latency compensation or handling timing discrepancies would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
The script captures audio input, processes it to detect drum hits, and attempts to compensate for input latency. However, I'm having difficulty achieving precise synchronization between the detected drum hits and the metronome ticks.

it is a heavy subject to implement by yourself and needs a lot of research and knowledge. i heavily recommend you to use a sound analysis library. i used this one before and it works pretty well. https://github.com/allanpichardo/Unity-Beat-Detection

Thank you for the advice. I'll try it.

Using a Coroutine for audio will never give good results.
What you can do is use OnAudioFilterRead callback, on any MonoBehavior with an AudioSource.
You can discard the incoming buffer, and use it for incoming audio processing, important bit is that it will come in sync with the audio thread, not Unity rendering thread, and will be synchronized.
Keep in mind you won't be allowed to touch most of Unity API in that thread, and you need to store the results and read them (via coroutine or otherwise)
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html

Thank you so much! Your insights were incredibly helpful. It was exactly what I needed to move forward with my project!

@СемёнГоргель good stuff. Would you mind accepting the answer?
